# Zend master slave mysql

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db, master-slave

I want to switch slave db if master fails. I found [Master/Slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826798/master-slave-switch-in-the-zend-framework-application-layer) switch, but its for reading writing (seems very logical, but not this case). Can you give " db failure" strategy in zend?

Answer (score 1):

look on this article

http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/10/02/database-replication-adapter-for-zend-framework-applications/

the classes is in

http://fedecarg.com/repositories/show/replicationadapter